# Rollup - No treeshaking with Typescript w/ Babel

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash, rollup, tree-shaking

I am not able to get tree-shaking for `lodash-es` when using ES6 import syntax. For example, the following seems to include all of lodash:

```
import { isArray} from 'lodash-es';
```

I am using the below lodash config:

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import pkg from './package.json';

const extensions = [
  '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx',
];

const name = 'RollupTypeScriptBabel';

export default {
  input: './src/index.ts',

  // Specify here external modules which you don't want to include in your bundle (for instance: 'lodash', 'moment' etc.)
  // https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#external-e-external
  external: [],

  plugins: [
    // Allows node_modules resolution
    resolve({ extensions }),

    // Allow bundling cjs modules. Rollup doesn't understand cjs
    commonjs(),

    // Compile TypeScript/JavaScript files
    babel({ extensions, include: ['src/**/*'] }),
  ],

  output: [{
    file: pkg.main,
    format: 'cjs',
  }, {
    file: pkg.module,
    format: 'es',
  }]
};
```

I have a test repo set up if anyone wants to try it out: https://github.com/jclangst/rollup-typescript-babel.

I've tried everything including other ES6 compatible libraries other than `lodash-es` and nothing works. What am I doing wrong that is preventing tree shaking?

Comment: This is basically why I stopped using lodash. :)

Comment: In case there turns out to be no good answer to this, I implore you to just take the easy path and use some babel import transformer like https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import. I've wasted all day and tried just about everything... don't be me.